# How do I SELECT dummy column dynamically if one or few columns do not exist in the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The SQL query I am trying is like this:-

```
select
  (select count(*) from ABC where AAA is not null) as AAA,
  (select count(*) from ABC where BBB is not null) as BBB,
  (select count(*) from ABC where CCC is not null) as CCC,
  (select count(*) from ABC where DDD is not null) as DDD;
```

Now the problem is that the table ABC exists in several schemas and in each schema it has different structure. Say in schema S1, the table abc has only two columns - AAA and CCC. In schema S2 it has all the four columns - AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD. So, I have taken the super structure of the table and created my query as above. Now what I want is that if the table in certain schema has only two columns than also it should display the 'NOT NULL' count for all four columns, showing NA for the columns not present.
 How should I achieve this?
NOTE: There are 50+ such tables with non-uniform structure across different schemas. So, I have to edit the SQL again and again for around 250 schemas for several tables.

Comment: Is it `Oracle` or `SQL-Server` ?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar SQL-Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the below. I am assuming that varchar(10) is big enough to hold your row count.

```
 SELECT 
  ( SELECT CASE WHEN NOT exists (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ABC' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'DDD') then 'NA' else CAST (COUNT(*) as varchar(10)) end 
    FROM abc AS t1
    WHERE aaa  IS NOT NULL
  ) AS AAA,
    ( SELECT CASE WHEN NOT exists (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ABC' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'DDD') then 'NA' else CAST (COUNT(*) as varchar(10)) end
    FROM abc AS t1
    WHERE bbb  IS NOT NULL
  ) AS BBB,
    ( SELECT CASE WHEN NOT exists (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ABC' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'DDD') then 'NA' else CAST (COUNT(*) as varchar(10)) end
    FROM abc AS t1
    WHERE CCC  IS NOT NULL
  ) AS CCC,
    ( SELECT CASE WHEN NOT exists (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ABC' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'DDD') then 'NA' else CAST (COUNT(*) as varchar(10)) end
    FROM abc AS t1
    WHERE DDD  IS NOT NULL
  ) AS DDD
FROM
  ( SELECT 1 AS AAA,1 as BBB, 1 as CCC, 1 as DDD
  ) AS dummy ;
```

Comment: Both the answers are correct. But I'll give it the right answer to you as I required it more for MS SQL. 
@ammoQ You are too good. Last time also you helped me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Since I borrowed many ideas from JamieA, it's only fair to accept his answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This answer is based on JamieA's answer, but it required several changes to make it work on Oracle and I didn't want to totally edit his answer*

This one works on Oracle.

```
SELECT 
  case when exists(select 1 from user_tab_columns
                 where table_name='ABC' and column_name='AAA') 
       then (select to_char(count(*)) FROM ABC WHERE AAA IS NOT NULL )
       else 'NA' end  AS AAA,
  case when exists(select 1 from user_tab_columns
                 where table_name='ABC' and column_name='BBB')
       then (select to_char(count(*)) FROM ABC WHERE BBB IS NOT NULL )
       else 'NA' end  AS BBB,
  case when exists(select 1 from user_tab_columns
                 where table_name='ABC' and column_name='CCC')
       then (select to_char(count(*)) FROM ABC WHERE CCC IS NOT NULL )
       else 'NA' end  AS CCC,
  case when exists(select 1 from user_tab_columns
                 where table_name='ABC' and column_name='DDD')
       then (select to_char(count(*)) FROM ABC WHERE DDD IS NOT NULL )
       else 'NA' end  AS DDD
FROM
  ( SELECT 1 AS AAA, 1 as BBB, 1 as CCC, 1 as DDD from dual
  );
```

Comment: That is simpler than mine, but OP requires to show 'NA' when the column does not exist. Did my answer not work as you expected?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll fix that. I guess your answer is for SQL-Server, while mine will be for Oracle.

Comment: @ammoQ This is quite what I wanted, but how should I display NA instead?

Comment: @ammoQ Indeed, the original question was tagged both Oracle and Sql Server, so now there is an answer for both!  Out of interest, what stops my answer from working on Oracle? I did a quick search and it appeared that INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS is present in Oracle

Comment: @JamieA No, INFORMATION_SCHEMA is not available on Oracle. (Don't let Oracle's MySQL documentation fool you). The way you combined the subqueries with the CASE causes a (rather inexplicible) "ORA-00937 not a single-group group function" error.